# How to write a custom Zend validator to check the hash of a file against a database record

Tags: file, zend-framework, hash, custom-validators

I'm building a file repository where each file has a database entry associated with it. In that database, I include the sha1 hash value for the file. Also, for security reasons, I rename each file with a specific pattern, so I can't check the filename directly via the form's filename value.

I'm trying to prevent people from uploading the same file twice, so I want to create a form validator that takes the file being uploaded and checks the hash of the file against all the values in the database. If the hash is already in the database--and thus the file already exists--the validator should return false. How access the file from inside the validator class so I can calculate the hash?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very badly asked. So I will not dig into the logic of it.<sup>*Sorry*</sup> Here is a very simple example of how you can create a Custom Validation Class.

The most important thing you need to remember is two methods.

1. `isValid()`: Returns either true or false through a logic
2. `getMessages()`: Returns errors messages in case of invalid.

Here is a basic example of comparing whether a user is admin or not.

```
class CustomValidate_UserAdmin extends Zend_Validate_Abstract
{
    $admin = "username"; //I am using a static value this time
 
    protected $_messageTemplates = array(
        self::FLOAT => "'%value%' is not an admin"
    );
 
    public function isValid($value)
    {
        $this->_setValue($value);
 
        if($this -> admin == $value) {     
             return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Now use it

```
$element->addValidator(new CustomValidate_UserAdmin('username'));
```

---

This is a very simple example to understand. You can replace it with your logic with a lot of ease I think.

## Updates

---

Add validation like this...

```
$element->addValidator(new CustomValidate_Hash('file/location', $hashvaluettocompare));
```

Now in your validation class

```
function isValid($location, $value) {
   if(hash_file("md5", $location)==$value) return true;
}
```

Comment: Ok, then riddle me this: How do I get the hash value for the file from inside the validator class?  The parameter $value is a string. I need to access the file itself in order to calculate the hash.

Comment: Send the location of the file and hash value in place of string and compare the hash values

Answer (score 1):

The validator you're looking for already exists it is part of [Zend_File_Transfer](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.file.transfer.validators.html) which is used by [Zend_Form_Element_File](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.file). It accepts an array to validate against.

another option would be to do the check in the controller, because you have to hash the file doing it as form validator presents difficulties.
So hash the file in the controller prior to calling ->receive() and use the Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists. Might be just as easy to do this with a method in your model. You could also use this validator when creating a method that hashes the file.

The [Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Abstract](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/) api has a method getHash(), I believe you can call getHash() and validate against Db_NoRecordExists.

Good Luck!

Comment: This gets me closer to what I'm looking for, but not quite. If I'm not mistaken, this checks to see if the file's hash matches a particular set of values.  I'm trying to check that it does _not_ match a set of values. Specifically, I'm trying to see if the hash for this file does not correspond with any of the hash values stored in my database.

Comment: OK, now this is strange.  I wrote a validator that takes the hash as a parameter. I then went to the controller, calculated the hash and added the validator to the form's file element.  The validator is running, and is even returning false at the right time.

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to have any effect whatsoever when I run $form->isValid, no matter what values I pass to the method.  I'm obviously missing something here. I realize these are newbie questions, but hey, I am a newbie (as everyone has been at one time or another) ;)

Comment: @blainarmstrong post your validator code, it might help find the issue.